# Google sheets script moving all rows starting from specific row number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to script a verification button to move all rows from a specific row number.
They need to be moved down 1 row for historical log. Also a new row at the top (row 17) needs to be created with the same check boxes and todays date.
Please refer to [this link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vsmaa1oUR6IjalINsUvxowP-668d2st8e-pj2BlV9Cs)

Bonus question: Is it also possible as the owner of the sheet, to have the moved down "logged rows" protected from changes with scripting?

I'm not sure where to start.
I believe it's a simplified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75215944/google-apps-script-to-move-multiple-rows-based-on-column-value-not-using-onedi)

EDIT: I have realized that instead of copying multiple rows, I should "insert row".

I have now made some progress but it does not seem to work as I intend.
The script should select row 17 and insert a row below this.

Here's my script:

```
function veriFy() {
  

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange('A17');
var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

sheet.setCurrentCell(rangeToCopy);


var selection = sheet.getSelection();
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();


sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));


}
```

It does not add the row when running, only select "A17".
Though if "A17" is already selected, the script will in fact add the row successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You don't have to apologize :-)
It's Google Apps scripting, for Google Sheets.

I don't really know how to describe it better.

Comment: `It's Google Apps scripting, for Google Sheets. I don't really know how to describe it better.` We understand that it scripting; the question being asked of you is to explain, in more detail and with clarity, the details of the scenario that you outlined in the first paragraph. Would also note that you question must stand alone, and that you should not expect that users will/must open your spreadsheet to better understand your questions &/or your data. The "google-sheets" tag explicitly says `Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.`

Comment: I've looked at your question and sample data and your script. Putting aside the script for the moment, I am confused about the process that you have described. To be honest, I don't understand exactly what you are doing with row 17 and where it is being copied, and what it represents. I would like to help; would you please explain exactly what information is contained in the table on each sheet, and what the checkboxes means in the columns on rows 17 and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to

- insert a new row at Row 17
- move existing rows down a row
- Update the "new" Row 17 with today's date and the "Unverified" image
- update the "old" Row 17 with the "Verified" image.

---

```
function verifySheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  // insert row
  sheet.insertRowBefore(17);

  // insert date
  sheet.getRange('B17').setValue(new Date())

  // copy the UnVerified image from Cell A18 to Cell A17
  var imagesSheetname = "images"
  var imagesSheet = ss.getSheetByName(imagesSheetname)
  var rangeToCopy = imagesSheet.getRange("A1")
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange("A17"))

  // copy the Verified image from Cell A19 to Cell A18
  var rangeToCopy = imagesSheet.getRange("A2")
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange("A18"))
}
```

---

**Notes**

- `insertRowBefore(17)`: inserts a new row at row 17, and automatically inserts blank checkboxes in Columns D-F
- `sheet.getRange('B17').setValue(new Date())`: inserts current date into Column B
- Created new sheet 'images" and saved copies of the Unverified and Verified images in Cells A1 and A2. This avoids any problem where the following row does not, for any reason, have a copy of the "Verified" image

---

**SAMPLE-AFTER**

[image: after]

---

**SAMPLE-BEFORE**

[image: before]